# else if statement with different paremeters

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I making some statements for site, and can't understand, how to make such type of statement. 
Here is the code

```
function checkWindowSize() {
  var pageWidth = $(window).width();
  if (pageWidth < 751) {
    $('.tab-content div').removeClass('tab-pane');
    $('#myTabs a').removeAttr("data-toggle", "tab");
  }
  else if (pageWidth < 751 && $(window).scrollTop()>=580;) {
    $('#faq .col-sm-3').addClass('fixed-faq');
    $('.tab-content div').addClass('padd-top');
  }
  else {
    $('#faq .col-sm-3').removeClass('fixed-faq');
    $('.tab-content div').removeClass('padd-top');
    $('#myTabs a').attr("data-toggle", "tab");
    $('.tab-content div').addClass('tab-pane');
  };
};
$(window).load(checkWindowSize);
$(window).resize(checkWindowSize);
```

It works fine with just only checking width and statements if, and else, but when I try make else if, with 2 parameters of check, the whole code stop working.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: First loose `;` from `(pageWidth < 751 && $(window).scrollTop()>=580;)`. Second you `else if` will never execute.

Comment: Your if (pageWidth < 751) statement covers the case when the pageWidth is less than 751. That leaves all of the remaining else and else if dealing with windows that have a pageWidth of 751 or greater.

Your first else if, however, has a condition pageWidth < 751 && ... that can never be true. pageWidth can't be < 751 here, because the first if already took care of that case.

You probably need to rethink your conditions a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (pageWidth < 751 && $(window).scrollTop()>=580;)
```

Remove the semicolum from this line. Then move second else if condition as first and first condition to second.

Comment: like that if (pageWidth < 751 && $(window).scrollTop()>=580) {
             $('#faq .col-sm-3').addClass('fixed-faq');
             $('.tab-content div').addClass('padd-top');
         }
         else if (pageWidth < 751) 
         {
            $('.tab-content div').removeClass('tab-pane');
            $('#myTabs a').removeAttr("data-toggle", "tab");}